# IE9 javascript error when variable is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a textarea where I use javascript to check if there's something writen on it:

```
if (!editorInstance.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText()) {
    do some action
}
```

It works fine for firefox, but in IE9 I get this error telling it's a null or undefined object (so IE doesnt check my condition).
so I tried:

```
var hasText = editorInstance.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText();
if (typeof hasText === 'undefined') {
    do some action
}
```

The problem is that it still stops in the first line ( `var hasText = edit...` ), because the `editorInstance.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText()` returns null or undefined

**EDIT**

when I do `editorInstance.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText()`, I get all text entered in the textarea, but when there's no text entered (I check it to validate this field), this code returns nothing, this is why the `hasText` variable is not working the way I expected.

Any idea about how can I solve it?

Comment: Which part is it telling you is null?

Comment: perhaps `body` has no children?

Comment: Perhaps `editorInstance` itself is null?

Comment: sorry.. I'll edit the question

Comment: You still haven't shown us the error message.

Comment: Where are `getBody()`, `getChild()` and `getText()` from? Those aren't native JS.

Comment: what do you see if you add a `console.log(hasText, typeof hasText);` after you declare the hasText variable?

Comment: What WYSWYG editor are you using? Is it supported in IE? By the way you need to check which item is undefined starting from left (e.g. editorInstance, editorInstance.document, editorInstance.document.getBody, etc)

Comment: I have a conference call at this time and i'll be back in abt a half an hour

Comment: @Cerbrus: I assume he’s using the CKEditor. It uses exactly those method names.

Comment: i'm back.. so.. i'm using ckeditor, like @Martijn said.

Comment: @OllyHodgson, it returns that 'hasText' is not defined

Comment: @periback2: if you try the code in my answer, does it work then?

Comment: @periback2 Try adding logging for each of the rungs on the ladder then - `console.log(editorInstance)`, `console.log(editorInstance.document)` and so on - see which one comes back broken? Might be a "can't see them in this scope/context" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the presence of each variable and function result that you refer to.

```
var firstChild = editorInstance && editorInstance.document && editorInstance.document.getBody() && editorInstance.document.getBody().getChild(0);
if (!firstChild || firstChild.getText() === '') {
    // do some action
}
```

`&&` is Javascript's [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).  It’s very handy for cases like this, when you want to fetch an object's value, but the object itself might be **null** or **undefined**.

Consider the following statement:

```
var doc = editorInstance && editorInstance.document;
```

It means the same as

```
var doc;
if (editorInstance) {
    doc = editorInstance.document;
} else {
    doc = editorInstance;
}
```

but it's shorter.  This statement will not error out if `editorInstance` is **null**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function test() {
    var editor_val1 = CKEDITOR.instances.id1.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText() ;
    var editor_val2 = CKEDITOR.instances.id2.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText() ;
    var editor_val3 = CKEDITOR.instances.id3.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText() ;

    if ((editor_val1 == '') || (editor_val2 == '') || (editor_val3 == '')) {
        alert('Editor value cannot be empty!') ;
        return false ;
    }

    return true ;
}
```